Confidence interval when extrapolating/estimating national result from state data
I have cancer incidence data for about 40% of the US, and want to use this to derive a national incidence estimate. I have age-sex specific incidence data and can use these to extrapolate. What would be the best way to derive a confidence interval for this estimate?

Do you believe that age and sex are the only factors that may affect cancer incidence? If so, then you can derive uncertainty quantification solely by scaling your sample with the population numbers per age-sex category. However, there is likely other factors at play; i.e., geographic region, population density, etc. If you do not have these data recorded, then you would want to account for these latent factors when quantifying your uncertainty.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@RonSnow is correct. In effect you are wanting to estimate something about a large population from a sample that is not random, and that is not likely to be representative of the whole population. Fisher would say that the data that you have comes from 'identifiable subsets' of the population.

To expand on what others are saying: confidence intervals only apply when you have a random sample of the population. So if your 40% is not random, then the logic of confidence intervals doesn't make sense. And the extent to which  it makes sense at all to use these data to estimates national prevalence depends a lot on where it comes from (is it just people from 6 states? Just people with college degrees?).  So we can't help without more details about where this "40%" came from.
